# VB.NET get last changed project date

Tags: vb.net

Good morning,

When I want to show the project name & version I use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion
```

Is there a similar thing for the last changed date of a project?
At the moment I have a valid workaround (see below), but I wonder if there is a build in solution like with the ones above.

```
Dim strFile = Application.StartupPath & "\" & Application.ProductName & ".exe" 
Return System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFile.ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the version be more important than the date when the project was built? Seems there is something wrong with version control/versioning  if version number is not enough. Also I don't think there is any built in functionality for this because there are version numbers.

Comment: The version is indeed the most important one.
But sometimes customers want to see when the last update/build was.
And it is for that, that we always want to add this as well.

Comment: You can always add a variable inside the assembly that contains a date (versioning is not much more than this), but I don't see what that tells you when you can build the software every day with the same version and "date variable value" so it won't be the "first built date" :) But it's definitely doable. Or make a database table with version numbers and release dates and fetch data from there if needed.

Comment: I use a slight variation `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Application.ExecutablePath).ToShortDateString`